# Preciso fazer uma seleção automatica

Tags: javascript, jquery, classes, tampermonkey

Olá,gostaria de ajuda para executar um comando de seleção automática nisto:

```
<select tabindex="-1" class="select-large"><option value="-">[Escolha...]</option> <option value="[object Object]"> NOMEDAPESSOA </option></select>
```

Pois estou fazendo um projeto que ao entrar na página aparece o nome de varias pessoas para selecionar e isso é muito chato, pois qualquer pessoa da lista serve.. Então baixei o tampermonkey e preciso de um código que clique e selecionar uma pessoa aleatória da lista.

Comment: Oi lololololo, bem vindo à comunidade! 
Esse html que tens `value="[object Object]"` vem de onde? Assim como está não vais poder usar o valor desse select. Porque precisas do `tampermonkey`? é para a funcionalidade que perguntas aqui?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Elementos
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');

//Cria um número randômico entre 0 e 1
//Multiplica pela quantidade de opções
//Arredonda para o inteóiro mais prximo
let op = Math.round(Math.random() * (options.length - 1));

console.log(op);

//Define o valor do select para o valor de uma das opção da lista
select.value = options[op].value;
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou, muito obrigado !!

```js
//Elementos
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');

//Cria um número randômico entre 0 e 1
//Multiplica pela quantidade de opções
//Arredonda para o inteóiro mais prximo
let op = Math.round(Math.random() * (options.length - 1));

console.log(op);

//Define o valor do select para o valor de uma das opção da lista
select.value = options[op].value;
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```